# Produce the set G, Transitive Closure

Tags: discrete-mathematics

the question is this,

> Let V = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}. Let E = {(0, 1),(1, 2),(2, 3),(3, 4)}. Let G = {(vi
>   , vj )|vi
>   , vj ∈ V, ∃vk ∈
>   V (vi
>   , vk) ∈ E ∧ (vk, vj ) ∈ E. Produce the elements in G

Im just not sure how to read

> vi
>   , vj ∈ V, ∃vk ∈
>   V (vi
>   , vk) ∈ E ∧ (vk, vj ) ∈ E.

my best guess is that G is empty because there are no three elements that satisfy, (vi, vk) and (vk, vj) and (vi, vj)

Comment: Do you know what "transitive closure" means?

Comment: @saulspatz apparently not, the only reason I titled it that was because that was the only word I was given to describe this.

Comment: The question seems a little odd to me.  The transitive closure of a binary relation $R$ is the smallest binary relation $T$ such that $R\subseteq T$ and $T$ is transitive.  The $G$ described in the question doesn't appear to be the transitive closure of $E$, but rather the set of elements that have to be added to $E$ to get the transitive closure.  As I see it, $G$ is neither transitive not a superset of $E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of $G$ are of the form $(v_i,v_j)$ such that you should be able to find $v_k\in V$ such that $(v_i,v_k)$ and $(v_k,v_j)$ are in $E$. Like $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$ are in $E$ and $0,1,2$ are in $V$ so $(0,2)$ is in $G.$ Like wise you can write other elements.